# Applying animation to identical armature with Action Editor does not work

Tags: animation, actions

I am trying to apply animation from one mixamo armature to another. They should be identical. I am using the action editor data-block approach as per the first section of this video tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYrz0U4RApk

However, it absolutely will not work not matter what I try.

- Download a simple un-animated y-bot from mixamo with an armature.
- Ensure the scale is correct, there are no animation key frames, and transforms are applied.
- Download a mixamo animation and import it into blender.
- As per the video, switch to the dope sheet and the action editor, and with the target armature selected, switch to the animation from the downloaded fax or bvh.

Ensure you are in pose position and play back.

Nothing. Nada. Zip.

I have half managed to get something, where the character remains t-pose and moves about. Mostly I get no change to the animation at all. Note, the imported animation plays back fine, but I cannot get it to switch to the un-animated rig.

Can anybody make this work?

PS...I am happy to provide a blend file if that would help. But the process ought to be as easy as I have outlined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that not all mixamo armatures are the same.

The safe way of proceeding is to make sure that the armature you intend to retarget is exactly the same. Even then there can still be surprises.

Either assign the animation on the Mixamo website and then download so that all the animations definitely have the same armature, or if you have a character in blender with a mixamo armature, UPLOAD that armature to mixamo, apply the animations and then download. It should then work.

Hopefully.